How do I prevent significant letters from stacking in ggplot with two variables?
I have a df with two variables, genotype and treatment; in a second dataframe I already have significance letters associated with the combination of both variables. So genotype1:treatment1 might be A, genotype1:treatment2 B etc.
I would like the letters to be plotted below or above the corresponding genotype boxplot.
Example code:
# Load the necessary library
library(ggplot2)

# Example data (replace with your own data)
set.seed(123)
treatment <- rep(c("Treatment1", "Treatment2"), each = 25)
genotype <- rep(c("Genotype1", "Genotype2", "Genotype3", "Genotype4", "Genotype5"), times = 10)
value <- rnorm(50, mean = 10, sd = 2)
data <- data.frame(treatment, genotype, value)

# Example dataframe with letters for significance
significance_df <- data.frame(
  treatment = c("Treatment1", "Treatment1", "Treatment2", "Treatment2"),
  genotype = c("Genotype1", "Genotype2", "Genotype3", "Genotype4"),
  letters = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
)

# Calculate x-coordinate for each letter
significance_df$x_pos <- with(significance_df, ave(as.numeric(treatment), treatment, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x)))

# Create the boxplot
ggplot(data, aes(x = treatment, y = value, fill = genotype)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Value", title = "Boxplot of Treatment vs Value by Genotype") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Genotype1" = "blue", "Genotype2" = "red", "Genotype3" = "green", "Genotype4" = "orange", "Genotype5" = "purple")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(data = significance_df, aes(label = letters, y = 7, x = x_pos), vjust = -1)



Unfortunatelly this results in the letters stacking on the treatment positions making them indistinguishable.

Is there a way to control the position of the letters on the x direction to make them correspond with the boxplots?

To achieve your desired result complete your dataset for the labels to include all combos of treatment and genotype, then map treatment on x in geom_text and use position = position_dodge(.75) to dodge your labels:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

significance_df <- significance_df |>
  tidyr::complete(
    treatment,
    genotype = factor(genotype, levels = paste0("Genotype", 1:5))
  ) |>
  tidyr::replace_na(list(letters = ""))

ggplot(data, aes(x = treatment, y = value, fill = genotype)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Treatment", y = "Value", title = "Boxplot of Treatment vs Value by Genotype") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "Genotype1" = "blue", "Genotype2" = "red",
    "Genotype3" = "green", "Genotype4" = "orange",
    "Genotype5" = "purple"
  )) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_text(
    data = significance_df, aes(
      label = letters, y = 7, x = treatment
    ),
    position = position_dodge(.75)
  )


